# Why does Ionic 4 use CSS property "contain" when it is not supported on iOS 10?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

Ionic 4 uses css property "contain" on ion-content. As far as I understand, this is not supported on iOS 10 and marked as experimental on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/contain). In my build for iOS 10, it results in layout quirks such as not being able to scroll to the bottom in scrollable content. I consider this to be the cause, because if I inspect the runtime build on iPhone 5 iOS 10, the css property "contain" is marked as "not supported". Iphone 6 iOS 11+ builds works fine.

I am confused Ionic 4 uses this property, since the documentation says iOS 10 is supported [browser support](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/intro/browser-support#ios-10). Am I misunderstanding something or maybe a workaround exists so I can support iOS 10?

Inspecting ion-content element shows "contain" property as the last item:

```
:host {
--background: var(--ion-background-color, #fff);
--color: var(--ion-text-color, #000);
--padding-top: 0px;
--padding-bottom: 0px;
--padding-start: 0px;
--padding-end: 0px;
--keyboard-offset: 0px;
--offset-top: 0px;
--offset-bottom: 0px;
--overflow: auto;
display: block;
position: relative;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-ms-flex: 1;
flex: 1;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0!important;
padding: 0!important;
font-family: var(--ion-font-family,inherit);
contain: layout size style;
```

}

Comment: Please place a part of code to guide you

Comment: _“it results in layout quirks such as […]”_ - and you are sure those are due to _that_? Because as far as I can see, this property only allows the browser to optimize rendering performance, but it should not have an effect on the layout if it is _not_ supported …

Comment: Sounds more like a question you should ask directly to the company that created the framework.

Comment: Mark Baijens, I raised an issue on Ionic GitHub.